# Calculate area of adjacent pixels

Tags: qgis, raster, r, area

I have a raster layer of seasonal lakes created from snowmelt runoff. I would like to calculate the size of the lakes that are created. So I want to basically calculate the area of pixels clustered together, see image. In the image, I would end up calculating the area of four temporary lakes.

Is there a way to do that in R or QGIS?

[image: lakes]

Comment: If that is all the data you have you can convert it to polygons, dissolve, multipart to singlepart and calculate an area column. But with a large raster it will be slow

Comment: Unfortunately, that is only a snippet of the data. It is global. I tried that before, and it crashed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using the {terra} R package:

```r
library(terra)
#> terra 1.5.39

# prep example data -------------------------------------------------------
f = system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r = rast(f)
r[r<400] = NA
plot(r)
```

[image]

```r
# detect "lakes" ----------------------------------------------------------
rp = patches(r)
plot(rp)
```

[image]

```r
# convert to polygons and calculate areas ---------------------------------
p = as.polygons(rp)
p$area = expanse(p)
p$area
#>  [1] 639851488.0   1660503.6    553747.8   3878757.1    554127.4    554601.7
#>  [7]    554791.3   1666817.3   2779091.9   1112329.1    556306.5   2225759.0
#> [13]   1113180.5    556779.4    556873.9   1114031.3    557157.4    557251.9
#> [19]    557251.9   8921505.5   5592676.1    559798.4   1679845.8    559892.6
#> [25]    559892.6

plot(p, "area")
```

[image]

Comment: The last step would be better like this: `zonal(cellSize(rp), rp, sum)`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the raster to points, group the points with DBSCAN, drop duplicates to keep one point per cluster, multiply the pixel size with each point clusters size:

[image]

[image]